# Pypy memory usage increases when nothing new is allocated

Tags: python, memory, out-of-memory, pypy

I'm not sure if this is a duplicate of the other PyPy memory questions, but here I'll provide a concrete example.

```
from __future__ import division

def mul_inv(a, m):
    """Modular multiplicative inverse, a^-1 mod m. Credit: rosettacode.org"""
    m0 = m
    x0, x1 = 0, 1
    if m == 1: return 1
    while a > 1:
        assert m != 0, "a and m must be coprime"
        q = a // m
        a, m = m, a%m
        x0, x1 = x1 - q * x0, x0
    if x1 < 0: x1 += m0
    return x1


M = 1000000009
L = 10**8

bin2 = [0] * L
bin2[0] = 1
for n in range(L-1):
    bin2[n+1] = (bin2[n] * (4*n + 2) * mul_inv(n+1, M)) % M
    if n % 10**5 == 0: print(n, bin2[n])

print(bin2[:20])
```

With python 3.6, the program uses 3-4 GB at most and runs to completion (Armin Rigo's list change doesn't change this significantly). With python 2.7.13 running PyPy 5.10.0, the program reaches 8 GB (how much RAM I have) quickly and freezes. Even with `gc.collect()` calls the program runs out of memory when `n` is about 3.5 * 10^7.

Where is this memory usage coming from? The only large memory usage should be initializing `bin2` as a 10^8 int list. Nothing else should be increasing the memory usage, under the assumption that all the local variables in `mul_inv` are garbage collected.

Comment: `range(L-1)` will create a list that is at least `10**8*24` bytes large, since every `int` object requires about `24` bytes in CPython, not sure in PyPy. So try it with `xrange`.

Comment: Although, reading a bit, PyPy may optimize the `for i in range(x)` loop to not actually materialize the whole list.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga `range` has never been a problem for me in the past. For example I have a Sieve of Eratosthenes function that does something like `range(10**8)` with no issue.

Comment: ``Nothing else should be increasing the memory usage`` - well no, each new ``long`` object stored in the list takes some extra memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oops, it's a bad case of the optimization for lists of integers.  The problem is that this starts as a list of ints:

```
bin2 = [0] * L
```

This is internally stored as an array of ints.  It's usually much more compact, even though in this case it doesn't change anything---because on CPython it's a list containing `L` copies of the same object `0`.

But the problem is that pretty soon, we store a `long` in the list.  At this point, we need to turn the whole list into the generic kind that can store anything.  But!  The problem is that we see 100 million zeroes, and so we create 100 million `0` objects.  This creates instantly 3 GB of memory pressure for nothing, in addition to 800MB for the list itself.

We can check that the problem doesn't occur if we initialize the list like this, so that it really contains 100 million times the same object:

```
bin2 = [0L] * L     # Python 2.x
bin2[0] = 1
```

That said, in your example you don't need the list to contain 100 million elements in the first place.  You can initialize it as:

```
bin2 = [1]
```

and use `bin2.append()`.  This lets the program start much more quickly and without any large memory usage near the beginning.

Note that PyPy3 still uses more memory than CPython3.

Comment: Thank you for your helpful analysis. However memory usage still grows even with `gc.collect()`. Do you know how I could mitigate this? I'm puzzled as to where this additional memory usage is even coming from.

Comment: Memory usage continues to grow because the loop is replacing the copies of 0 (a small integer) with ``long`` objects, which take more space.  Understanding the issue is easier on PyPy2.  On Python3 all integers are the same, but PyPy3 optimizes small integers more than integers that would be ``long`` on Python2 (even if obtained e.g. from ``(very_large-very_large)``, which gives a "large" 0 instead of a "small" 0; this could be optimized too)

Comment: We just did an optimization that happen to fix the problem here: now ``any_long_number % small_int`` returns a small integer in PyPy3, because it can (unlike on PyPy2 where this is defined by the language to return a ``long`` object).  As we store in the ``bin2`` list values that are all ``% M``, this keeps ``bin2`` being a list of small integers and this should consume quite a bit less memory than CPython now.

Answer (score 1):

AFAICT the issue here is that you're assigning longs to the array, and despite your modulo, PyPy doesn't seem to notice that the number still fits into a machine word.

I can think of two ways to fix this:

1. Pass the value assigned to `bin2[n+1]` through `int()`.
2. Use `array.array()`.

The former only affects PyPy2, and results in what appears to be a stable memory footprint of ~800MB on my Mac, whereas the latter appears to stabilise at ~1.4GB regardless of whether I run it in PyPy2 or PyPy3.

I haven't run the program fully to completion, though, so YMMV…